# issue with 2d array and printing

Tags: vb.net

```
Option Explicit On
Option Strict On
Public Class SurveyForm


    Structure Question
        Dim QuestionString As String

    End Structure
    Structure Answer
        Dim AnswerInteger As Integer

    End Structure
    Private QuestionGroup(9) As Question
    Private AnswerGroup(9, 4) As Answer
    Private indexinteger As Integer = 0

    Private Sub QuestionGroupBox_Enter(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles QuestionGroupBox.Enter

    End Sub

    Private Sub ExitButton_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles ExitButton.Click
        Me.Close()

    End Sub

    Private Sub SurveyForm_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Dim always As Integer
        Dim never As Integer
        Dim seldom As Integer
        Dim sometimes As Integer
        Dim usually As Integer

        If AlwaysRadioButton.Checked = True Then always += 1
        If NeverRadioButton.Checked = True Then never += 1
        If SeldomRadioButton.Checked = True Then seldom += 1
        If SometimesRadioButton.Checked = True Then sometimes += 1
        If UsuallyRadioButton.Checked = True Then usually += 1

        AlwaysRadioButton.Checked = False
        NeverRadioButton.Checked = False
        SeldomRadioButton.Checked = False
        SometimesRadioButton.Checked = False
        UsuallyRadioButton.Checked = False

        QuestionGroup(0).QuestionString = "Question 1: Do you read the textbook chapter after class"
        QuestionGroup(1).QuestionString = "Question 2: Do you complete the homework when it is assigned"
        QuestionGroup(2).QuestionString = "Question 3: Do attend class regularly"
        QuestionGroup(3).QuestionString = "Question 4: Do you participate in class discussions"
        QuestionGroup(4).QuestionString = "Question 5: Do you participate in a study group"
        QuestionGroup(5).QuestionString = "Question 6: Do you answer questions in the textbook"
        QuestionGroup(6).QuestionString = "Question 7: Do you practice with the hands on excersice"
        QuestionGroup(7).QuestionString = "Question 8: Do you try little projects to test all new topics"
        QuestionGroup(8).QuestionString = "Question 9: Do you ask questions when you are unsure about a topic?"
        QuestionGroup(9).QuestionString = "Question 10: Do you use the online help to learn more about each feature?"
        AnswerGroup(0, 0).AnswerInteger = always


    End Sub

    Private Sub BeginSurveyButton_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles BeginSurveyButton.Click


        QuestionLabel.Text = QuestionGroup(indexinteger).QuestionString
        If indexinteger < QuestionGroup.Length Then
            indexinteger += 1


            If indexinteger = 10 Then
                QuestionLabel.Text = "Thank you for completing the survey"
            End If
        End If

        BeginSurveyButton.Text = "Next Question"

        If indexinteger = 10 Then
            BeginSurveyButton.Enabled = False

        End If


        If AlwaysRadioButton.Checked = False Then
            If NeverRadioButton.Checked = False Then
                If SeldomRadioButton.Checked = False Then
                    If SometimesRadioButton.Checked = False Then
                        If UsuallyRadioButton.Checked = False Then
                            MessageBox.Show("Please select an answer", "Invalid Answer", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation)
                            indexinteger -= 1

                        End If
                    End If
                End If
            End If

        End If

        PrintButton.Enabled = False
        NextButton.Enabled = False

        If indexinteger = 10 Then
            PrintButton.Enabled = True
            NextButton.Enabled = True

        End If


    End Sub

    Private Sub AlwaysRadioButton_CheckedChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles AlwaysRadioButton.CheckedChanged, NeverRadioButton.CheckedChanged, SeldomRadioButton.CheckedChanged, SometimesRadioButton.CheckedChanged, UsuallyRadioButton.CheckedChanged




    End Sub

    Private Sub NextButton_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles NextButton.Click
        NextButton.Enabled = False
        PrintButton.Enabled = False
        BeginSurveyButton.Enabled = True
        QuestionLabel.Text = QuestionGroup(0).QuestionString
        NeverRadioButton.Checked = False
        AlwaysRadioButton.Checked = False
        SeldomRadioButton.Checked = False
        SometimesRadioButton.Checked = False
        UsuallyRadioButton.Checked = False

    End Sub
End Class
```

okay here is my code 
the task is to create a project in which the user will complete a 10 question survey. create a form containing labels with each of the following questions and a group of radio buttons for each question with the following responses: always, usually, sometimes, seldom, and never
use a 2d array to accumulate the number of each response for each question have a menu or button option that will print an item analysis on the printer that shows the question number and the count for each response
im trying to print the sum of the answers for multiple surveys im wondering how do i go about doing that

Answer (score 0):

You have to rely on the events of the corresponding controls to update the global variables (`always`, `never`, etc.). Your current code just checks for what happens at the start, not after the user has performed any change. In principle, it should be enough with the default event for each control (i.e., the one whose method is generated after double-clicking on this control on the design view). For example:

```
Private Sub AlwaysRadioButton_CheckedChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles AlwaysRadioButton.CheckedChanged
    If (AlwaysRadioButton.Checked) Then
        always += 1
    End If
End Sub
```

This code adds one to the `always` variable every time the `AlwaysRadioButton` is checked. But bear in mind that you have to manage the events individually; thus don't associated more than one event per method (the one VB generates by default).